# Is there a limit on number of handles to system registry in XP?

Tags: registry, windows-xp, filehandle

Very rarely, one of my application instances will fail to find a registered class/dll in registry. I suspect this could be due to failure to read the registry. Does Windows XP impose a limit on the number of active file handles to registry? This is besides the absolute handles limit.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an upper limit to all handles. But it is completely beyond the bounds of imagination that you should be hitting it. There is certainly enough headroom for multiple running applications to have several registry handles open simultaneously.

The only way that you would ever reach such a limit would be if you were not properly *closing* the handles when you were finished with them, resulting in a leak. Make sure you are calling the [`RegCloseKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724837.aspx) function for each handle that you open.

Comment: Does the Paged Pool Size and Registry Size Limit have any role to play in this issue?